# Error starting service: Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу windows service. 
У меня собственно три файла: add_to_startup.py (добавляет мой сервис в автозагрузку), run_as_a_service.py (запускает мою программу как сервис) и test.py (сама программа).

Екзешник делаю pyinstaller-ом:

```
pyinstaller -F --onefile --hidden-import=win32timezone run_as_a_service.py test.py add_to_startup.py
```

При попытке запуска сервиса пишет:

```
Error starting service: Служба не ответила на запрос своевременно.
```

Если убрать импорт test и исполнение функции test.service(), то сервис запускается и работает нормально.

run_as_service.py:

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import sys
import time
import test

class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "test"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test"
    _svc_description_ = "test test"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.isAlive = False
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.isAlive = True
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                                servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                                (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        while self.isAlive:
            test.service()
            time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(AppServerSvc)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

test.py:

```
import add_to_startup

def service():
    print("Hello world")
```

add_to_startup.py:

```py
#adding program to startup
import os
import getpass

USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()

def add_to_startup(file_path=""):
    if file_path == "":
        file_path = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test\dist\run_as_a_service.exe'
    bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME
    with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+", encoding = "cp866") as bat_file:
        bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)

add_to_startup()
```